# Playing animation to a specific time

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am creating a *backend* for animating a progress bar.

```
// Default easing.
TweenLite.defaultEase = Power0.easeNone;

// Timeline.
var tl = new TimelineLite({
    onUpdate : function()
    {
        console.log(progress.progress);
    }
});

// Initial state.
var progress = { progress : 0 };

// Finalized state.
tl.to(progress, 1, { progress : 100 });

// The length of the animation.
tl.totalDuration(15);

// Play.
tl.play();
```

This works as expected, but is there a way to **animate from current playhead to a specific one**? Something like `tl.playTo(0.5)` and afterwards `tl.playTo(0.2)` that would revert to 20%.

I am aware of `seek`, `progress` and the optional variable for `play` methods, but they only let me specify the starting position, not the end position.

How do I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what I propose.

You can animate the **`progress`** property of **`TimelineLite`**. Something like:

`TweenLite.to(tl, 1, {progress: .5, ease: Linear.easeNone});`.

Also, have you seen [**`tweenTo()`**](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/tweenTo/) and [**`tweenFromTo`**](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/tweenFromTo/) that are available in **`TimelineMax`** and I know that you are using **`TimelineLite`** but I am still wondering if you were aware of them.

Does this help?